# Ubuntu shows a grey error dialog message on load when I enter password

Tags: 11.10

when I boot up my Ubuntu VM I get - "could not connect to session bus: //bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message"

Does anyone know how to fix this, or even diagnose it?  I'm really new to using this OS and I was trying to install Maven if that's any help.

Thanks,

David

EDIT : Virtualisation == VMWare, host = Windows 7

EDIT 2 : OK so it looks like I broke my /etc/environment

When I login to ubuntu (by pressing ctrl-alt-f2) if I try to do "sudo nano /etc/environment" I get "The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.

Does this help at all? :)

Comment: What virtualization technology ? Virtualbox ? VMWare ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with....
Login to the console (ctrl-alt-f2) and issue the command:
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin

Then I was able to get into the GUI